# Replacing dining room Light switch : 4 wires, what is the pink for?

Tags: electrical, switch

I wanted yesterday to replace my dining room light switch. However, when I looked at it I found 4 wires :
- Black (Hot)
- White (Neutral)
- Copper (Ground)
- PINK ???????

The light switch I had bought at Home Depot only could accomodate the Black, White and Ground wire ? Do I need to buy a special light switch ?
Should I cap the pink wire as my dining room lamp is not a ceiling fan any more ?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Pink is commonly fan power, is it capped off in the ceiling box?

Comment: Great question, I have replaced the fan by a light fixture 2 months ago and don't remember if I capped off the pink wire (or if it as already capped off), I will take the fixture apart and let you know

Comment: I'm sure someone more knowledgeable will weigh in, but I'd assume you'd just cap it off on both ends and wire the switch without it.

Comment: That sounds very probable. However, I found the same pink wire for a kitchen switch that didn't have a fan. (But its possible that the previous owner had removed a fan)

Comment: Actually, I just removed my light fixture and didn't find any pink wire!! I didn't remember seeing it when I remove the ceiling fan 2 months ago but now Im wondering what the pink wire is for. Could it be the line ? (vs the black being the load or vice versa)

Comment: Maybe the light fixture was originally controlled by two ("3-way") switches, then someone put in a fan and reconnected the wires for a single pole switch. Then you come along and remove the fan and wonder what the pink is.

Comment: Multi-conductor cables, used by most houses, have standard color codes: bare, white, black for /2 cable;  also red on /3, and also {blue or white/red} on a {/4 or /2/2}.  These are stock colors, and their usage is defined by well, how they're used.

Comment: @Harper would pink be a version of red? I assumed this house in wired in NM cable, but is this wired in conduit?

Comment: It's probably just an old red insulator that has faded to pink. I would leave it capped for now. If everything still has power, you're all set. if one or more devices is no longer powered, it was probably that conductor that was supplying them - reconnect it to the hot (black) supply in that box.

Comment: My house is from 1983 is that can help ?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the box in question?

Comment: Sure, I added a picture in my original post

Comment: That appears to be a three way switch with the white being used as either hot or common. (usually all the whites are just twisted together in the back of switch boxes, if it's attached to one of the poles on the switch then it can be expected to be supplying current when the switch is on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like this is a three-way switch, or at least wired for a three-way at some point in time.

You will need a different switch, specifically a three-way switch, and it should be wired in the same way as the existing switch.

You should locate the other switch that controls that fixture to confirm its existence.  If it doesn't exist, then the pink wire was probably used as power to the fan, but in that case I would expect this would be in a double-gang box.

Comment: I also thought it could be a three-way switch but then it doesn't make sense that the same "pink" wire is in the master bedroom switch ( a 3 way switch in the bedroom, really ?), in the kitchen switches....

Comment: There have been times I have used 14-3 wire when I thought someone might want to add a fan. In the case where I put it in as a spare it was capped in a single gang box. If the "pink" was wired to the switch it is probably a 3 way.

Comment: Thanks, I have located the other switch. For the other switches where I saw a pink wire as well, it turns out that they don't have a "white" wire (the color white), hence I guess, the pink means "white".
Thanks!